# Thinkpad X230t Laptop External Monitor - Wrong Alignment

Tags: windows-10, laptop, thinkpad

When I plug in an external monitor into my Thinkpad X230 Tablet PC with a VGA port, and extend the display to that monitor, the monitor's display is shifted 3 inches to the right.  There is a large black gap on the left side of the monitor.

The monitor has a setting to manually adjust the display position, but only shifts about an inch at its max.  The gap is much larger than that.

Running Windows 10, latest updates.  I tried updating the Intel graphics drivers recently released on Lenovo's website, but no help.  Tried changing the resolution on that monitor, all had same exact gap on the left side.

Has anyone seen an issue like this?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the monitor resolution?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned in the post, I tried changing the resolution of the external monitor.  All resolutions produced the same gap on the left side.  Tried almost every resolution possible.

Comment: Sorry I shul have explained better, What happens when you try and change the resolution via the Intel software?

Comment: Okay. I tried the Intel HD Control Panel software, changed the resolution and other settings for the external monitor.  Always a 3 inch black bar on the left no matter what I try.  FYI, I have used this monitor and VGA cable on another computer, works fine.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it.  I did a "factory reset" on the monitor, and that did it.  Never seen a monitor behave that way, especially being so many inches off aligned, but that worked.  Thank you for your help!!